# iPad Air 2 Data Transfer

Tags: ios, ipad

I recently purchased a new iPad Air 2. My old iPad had the most recent iOS installed, and had been backed up. On some games, my data transferred, but on others, I lost all of my progress.

Comment: What is your question? Could you try rephrasing?

Comment: Adding the names of the games that had problems may be of help.

Answer (score 2):

Since most items seem to have transferred, it sounds like the games weren't included in the backup of your old iPad. It is also possible these games required you to sign in with the same Game Center account to associate the new device with your progress.